# Count occurrences of unique values in a column of one 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, counting, array-column

I currently have the following array:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user] => Name 1
            [group] => 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [user] => Name 2
            [group] => 1
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [user] => Name 3
            [group] => 2
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [user] => Name 4
            [group] => 2
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [user] => Name 5
            [group] => 3
        )
)
```

I am attempting to create a new array with the various `group` values as the key, then count how many are in each group to give the following:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 1
)
```

I have attempted to use the following, however I get undefined index warnings:

```
$newArr = array();
foreach ($details['user_groups'] as $key => $value) {
    $newArr[$value['user_groups']]++;
}
```

Comment: just to make sure, you are trying to get the `group` from the first array?

Comment: Yeah, so the range of groups from the first array (i.e. 1-3) as the keys of the new array and then count how many are in each group, again from the first array

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This can be done with a simple iteration:

```
$counts = array();
foreach ($array as $key=>$subarr) {
  // Add to the current group count if it exists
  if (isset($counts[$subarr['group']]) {
    $counts[$subarr['group']]++;
  }
  // or initialize to 1 if it doesn't exist
  else $counts[$subarr['group']] = 1;

  // Or the ternary one-liner version 
  // instead of the preceding if/else block
  $counts[$subarr['group']] = isset($counts[$subarr['group']]) ? $counts[$subarr['group']]++ : 1;
}
```

###Update for PHP 5.5

In PHP 5.5, which has added the [`array_column()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function to aggregate an inner key from a 2D array, this can be simplified to:

```
$counts = array_count_values(array_flip(array_column($array, 'group')));
```

Comment: `$counts[$subarr['group']++];`

Comment: I did try that Michael using the code I included on my question, however I get undefined index warnings.

Comment: @gerep Not as you have it :) I was missing a bracket, but already fixed it.

Comment: @lethalMango Did you try the current version I have there? It will not give undefined index warnings. Initially, I hit the save button before completing the if/else

Comment: Sorry I saw the first version :) Works a charm, I guessed I had missed something obvious! Thanks

Comment: is there another way without loop the array?

Comment: @OkiErieRinaldi If you have PHP 5.5 (which has `array_column()`) you could do `array_count_values(array_flip(array_column($array, 'group')))`.  Otherwise, see the array_map() example another user posted.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done with a simple `array_map` function

```
$array = array_map(function($element){
    return $element['group'];
}, $array1);

$array2 = (array_count_values($array));

print_r($array2);
```

Comment: Dear,@Vijaysinh Parmar where you defined $array1?

Comment: you can refer question array as $array1.

Comment: Dear @Vijaysinh Parmar thank you for such a prompt response.I used my own one but after your reply I prefer yours.Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your initial attempt was close.  You were simply using the wrong key inside the loop:

```
$newArr = array();
foreach ($details['user_groups'] as $key => $value) {
        // What you were using:
        // $newArr[$value['user_groups']]++;

        // What you should be using:
        $newArr[$value['group']]++;
}
```

Comment: So this was a typo question?  I do not endorse snippets that generate Warnings/Notices.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple but effective way

```
$count = call_user_func_array('array_merge_recursive', $Array);
echo count($count['user']).'<br>';
echo count($count['group']).'<br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$output = array();
  foreach($data as $key => $value){
    $output[$value['group']]['count']++;
}

$final = array();
foreach($output as $key => $value){
    $final[$key] = $value['count'];    
}

print_r($final);
```

```
//out put result:=========
Array(
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 1
)
```

Comment: Is that *out-put result* or *out-put final*? Please describe why this is the way to solve the problem (compared to, e.g. the more functional approach of existing answers), and how yours works.

Answer (score 0):

You only need two native function calls for this task.  Isolate the desired column of data with `array_column()`, then count the occurrences with `array_count_values()`.  This is the only way that I would code this task in one of my projects.

The added benefit of using `array_column()` is that if some of your subarrays do not contain the targeted column key, then there will be no Notice/Warning generated.  If you were to use a common looping technique or `array_map`/`array_walk()` instead, you might need to write conditional checks to prevent the Notices/Warnings.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/qflh2))

```
$array = [
    ['user' => 'Name 1', 'group' => 1],
    ['user' => 'Name 2', 'group' => 1],
    ['user' => 'Name 3', 'group' => 2],
    ['user' => 'Name 4', 'group' => 2],
    ['user' => 'Name 5', 'group' => 3],
];

var_export(
    array_count_values(array_column($array, 'group'))
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  1 => 2,
  2 => 2,
  3 => 1,
)
```