# Counting within a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, counting

I have an array like so:

```
$resellers =  Array
(
    [40] => Array
        (
            [state] => AB
            [city] => Calgary
        )

    [185] => Array
        (
            [state] => AB
            [city] => Calgary
        )

    [141] => Array
        (
            [state] => AB
            [city] => Calgary
        )

    [41] => Array
        (
            [state] => AB
            [city] => Grande Prairie
        )

    [68] => Array
        (
            [state] => BC
            [city] => Burnaby
        )

    [51] => Array
        (
            [state] => BC
            [city] => Campbell River
        )

    [61] => Array
        (
            [state] => BC
            [city] => Kamloops
        )
  )
```

I was wondering if there was an easy way for me to count how many values were for "Alberta" (which would be 4), and BC (which would be 3).

Comment: `foreach` and incrementing a counter isn't easy enough?

Comment: Possible Duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442230/php-getting-unique-values-of-a-multidimensional-array

Comment: What did you try so far? And what doesn't work from the *existing* QA material we have on the site already? For example [Counting Values in Multidimensional Array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10215659/367456)? Or [Count specific values in multidimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11558397/367456)?

Comment: I'd prefer to keep the code as simple and non-looping as possible.

Comment: @JiminyCricket: We like to keep this site as non-looping as possible, too. If you miss some answer with existing QA, post a comment there. As written, you're welcome to do your part of the homework first.

Comment: @JiminyCricket: Please leave your answer as an answer, not as part of the question. I've removed that part. You can still find it in the edit history.

Comment: Can you please stop editing my content hakre

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
array_count_values(array_map(function($item) {
   return $item['state'];
}, $resellers));
```

Comment: missing some closing brackets here

Comment: @JiminyCricket: I'm missing that you're not doing any (re-)search before asking a question.

Comment: Wasn't having luck with the topics I found. Thanks Cedrun, this set me on the right path. I solved it now.

Comment: Create solution... thx

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate through it to find the states you need.

```
function countState($data, $state) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach($data as $point)
        if($point['state'] === $state)
            $i++;

    return $i;
}

echo "Alberta found " . countState($array, "AB") . " times"!
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$arr = array(array('state'=>'AB', 'city'=>'Calgary'), ...); //your array 

function count_values( $arr, $value) {
 $count = 0;
 foreach($arr as $v) {
  foreach($v as $m) {
   if( $m['state'] === $value )
    $count++;
  }
 }
 return $count;
}

$count_ab = count_values($arr, 'AB');
$count_bc = count_values($arr, 'BC');
```

Comment: I imagine that in real life there will be more than two values to count.

Comment: This will be exactly the way to create Code Monster http://ow.ly/flqxz

Answer (score 0):

Solved with help from Cedrun's response.

Built array:

```
 $state_count = array_count_values( array_map(function($item){return $item['state'];}, $r_resellers));
```

Then to output:

```
echo $state_count["AB"];
```